# How to remove all label which is inside fieldset?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please explain how to remove all label which is inside `fieldset` ?

I've tried like this but it doesn't remove the label.

```
<fieldset class="ui-dform-fieldset">
            <input type="text" id="serverAddress" name="serverAddress" required="required" tabindex="1" onblur="validateElement('Ping', 'form_tc_1-cmd_1_Ping','serverAddress')" class="ui-dform-text valid">
            <legend class="ui-dform-legend">Server Address<span class="red"><span class="red"><span class="red"><span class="red"><span class="red"><span class="red">*</span></span>
                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
                </span>
            </legend>
            <label for="serverAddress" class="checked">✔</label>
        </fieldset>
```

How is it possible?I have this given HTML. I need to remove label which is inside the fieldset. I used this:

```
$("fieldset label").remove();
```

Comment: It is actually working ....

Comment: Yes it is working see this http://jsfiddle.net/ttpY3/1/

Comment: First of all, have you included jquery library into your html..?

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy: I'm suggesting to start from the beginning them and ask if OP has turned on their computer!

Answer (score 2):

You may try this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/x94YQ/)):

```
$(function(){
    $("fieldset > label").remove();
});
```

**Update:**

You may put code like this:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("fieldset > label").remove();
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

It's possible to put the `script` at bottom of the page before the closing body (`</body>`) tag.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there! Wrap your code in `DOM ready`:

```
$(function() {
    $("fieldset label").remove();
});
```